# nslookup show different addresses from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, nslookup

I have a domain portal.example.com which points to a ELB in AWS,and I have 3 instances behind the ELB.

and I did a

nslookup portal.exaple.com

```
Server:     75.75.75.75
Address:    75.75.75.75#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   portal.exaple.com
Address: xx.xx.x.188
Name:   portal.exaple.com
Address: xx.xx.xx.249
Name:   portal.exaple.com
Address: xx.xx.xxx.189
Name:   portal.exaple.com
Address: xx.xx.xxx.126
```

I wonder what are the 4 addresses? I assume they are not the IPs of my instances since I only have 3 instances behind the ELB.

Also, the 4 instances in my AWS account show completely different ips:

```
xx.xx.xxx.245
xx.xx.xx.148
xx.xx.xxx.166
xx.xx.xxx.130
```

I wonder what is going on here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Those are IP addresses for ELB instances (not your EC2 instances). AWS will create one or more ELB instances in every AZ that your ELB is set up to use. You can't see (or manage) those ELB instances, AWS manages them automatically in the background.

Comment: Assuming VPC, they should also be visible if you [look in `Network Interfaces` in the EC2 console](http://serverfault.com/a/831733/153161).  Each public IP has a corresponding priviate IP as well.